# TYPO3 9.5 Extension Builder throws Exception

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I try to create a new TYPO3 extension with the Extension Builder and get the following error:

```
Extension could not be saved: Could not generate action controller, error: PHP Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class in /var/www/html/public/typo3conf/ext/extension_builder/Classes/Parser/Utility/NodeConverter.php line 240
```

TYPO3 9.5.23
extension_builder 9.10.3

I tried two different installations (one is a plain installation with introduction_package).

Just very simple extension with
1 FE-Plugin

As soon as I add a model with a default action or a second table with a relation I get this error.

Comment: Perhaps Typo3 needs a specific version of PHP?

Comment: Well just checked it. Error occurs with PHP 7.2, 7.3 and 7.4.

Comment: Perhaps the contents of NodeConverter.php line 240?

Comment: If I don't mistake this is an error that can happen if try to use a foreign class or table in a model. Just remove the corresponding entry, save the extension and create the mapping-file manually.

Comment: Well I removed now the relations between my tables and all the default actions and added that stuff manually. But that is not the intention of the extension_builder so I consider this as a bug.